# How can I register another win32 message handler

Tags: c++, winapi

I want to change the message handler for an old legacy app we use but don't have the source for any more.  In a dll that we do have the source for I'm wanting to intercept the window messages and then pass them onto the app.  Is this possible?  I tried something along the lines of:

```
WNDPROC lpfnWndProc = NULL;

void GetHandler()
{
     HINSTANCE hInstance = GetModuleHandle(NULL);
     HWND hWnd = GetActiveWindow();

     WCHAR lpClassName[1024];

     GetClassName(hWnd,lpClassName,1024);

     WNDCLASSEX wc;

     GetClassInfoEx(hInstance, lpClassName, &wc);

     lpfnWndProc = wc.lpfnWndProc;

     wc.lpfnWndProc = NewMessageProc;

     RegisterClassEx(&wc);
}
```

However GetActiveWindow fails and just returns NULL.  Is there a simpler way to do this.  Infact I'd be happy if I could just simply add another message handler.

Comment: Important question: is your DLL loaded in the old application address space? If answser is NO, you should begin with addressing that (with DLL injection, maybe via Hooking). If the answser is yes, can you make your DLL code be executed in the SAME thread as the window you want to subclass?. If YES, use SetWindowSubclass, if NOT, use message hooking to "go" in the good thread, and then SubClass.

Comment: @manuell You cannot execute a .dll's code **without** loading it into an application's address space. Your question - as posted - doesn't make sense.

Comment: @IInspectable I was just asking if the DLL was loaded in the same process as the one hosting the window to subclass. What's the problem?

Comment: @user176168 Then, your only problem is to get the hWnd to subclass (with SetWindowSubclass). You should use FindWindow, or EnumWindows.

Answer (score 2):

It is not clear whether you want to subclass specific controls, or all windows of a particular window class.

If you want to subclass specific controls, the section [Subclassing Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773183.aspx) in the MSDN describes how to do this, both for ComCtl32.dll version 6 and above, and the legacy procedure of directly replacing a control's window procedure.

If you want to subclass all controls of a particular window class you would have to change the entries stored in the registered window class, using [`SetClassLongPtr`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633589.aspx). Note that this will only affect windows subsequently created with that window class. This is a bit of a Catch 22, as you need to have a window handle when calling `SetClassLongPtr`, limiting the applicability of subclassing a window class.

As for the code you posted, there are a number of issues:

Your call to `GetModuleHandle` retrieves the wrong `HINSTANCE`, namely that of the calling application. Since you need the module handle of the module that registers the window class you have to pass the name of the .dll that implements the controls.

Calling `GetActiveWindow` may or may not return a value, depending on whether or not the calling thread actually does have an active window. In your case it apparently doesn't, so you need another means of retrieving a window handle, such as [`FindWindowEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633500.aspx).

Your final call to `RegisterClassEx` doesn't do what you think: It will simply fail, since you cannot re-register a window class with the same name of an existing window class. You need to call `SetClassLongPtr` instead, as illustrated above.

Comment: Hi IInspectable my dll doesn't implement any controls and (I think) I want the applications main window as it will have the message proc I want to replace.  Actually my understanding of all of this is pretty poor.  Can I just create a local (invisible) control that has nothing to do with the original app (Ie just local to the dll)  and it will receive window messages without touching the original apps message handler?  Sorry for being a bit of n00b... Thanks

Comment: @user Creating an 'intercepting' control is not possible. Messages are not broadcast into the wild, but rather sent directly to the recipients when `DispatchMessage` is called. You have to intercept the message handling one way or another; subclassing controls is the cleanest approach to go about that.

Answer (score 1):

I'd actually use `SetWindowSubclass` after getting the HWND of the window you want to modify the behaviour of. SetWindowLong was deprecated as a way to change the WndProc of a window back around the time that CommCtrl.dll version 6 came out. MSDN can tell you all about that particular part of history and its motivation - just look up SetWindowSubclass.

As it stands, assuming the calling thread has an active window, your code will simply create a new window-class with the same attributes as your target window, albeit with a different WndProc - it wont set the wndproc of an existing window.. - (hence my mention of SetWindowLong and SetWindowSubclass)

**EDIT:** Or at leaast, it would of not for the oversight I made on that point. As pointed-out in a comment below, this call to RegisterClass will actually fail - you can't register the same className more than once.

You should also probably look at the `FindWindow` function - just give it a NULL `lpWindowName`, and the (known) class-name of the target window. In the event that the desired window is not the one that's returned, you could use `EnumWindows`. Simply call `GetClassName` in the callback function you supply to `EnumWindows`, subclassing any/all windows whose class-name matches the class-name of the target window.

Once this window has been subclassed, you can consume its messages as you wish, passing them onto the original window-proc as needed.

Comment: The calling thread will **not** create a new window class. The call to `RegisterClassEx` will simply fail. You cannot re-register a window class with the same name of an existing window class.

Comment: Good catch! Thanks (again) IInspectable.. :)